# Boostrap carousel is not resizing text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flat

I'm using Bootstrap with Flat UI framework, and I've come to a problem with Carousel.

I have my carousel code as:

```
<section>
<!-- slider obrázků-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- tečky které identifikují pořadí-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>   
    <!-- první slide-->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">       
        <img src="img/ZemOlymp4.JPG" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <!--text vypsaný uvnitř obrázku-->
              <h3>Vítězství v celostátní zemědělské soutěži</h3>
              <p>Jakub Procinger, student 3. ročníku agropodnikání na Městské střední odborné škole v Kloboukách u Brna, získal první místo na zemědělské olympiádě v Českých Budějovicích</p>
              <button class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary">Číst dále</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- druhý slide -->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/DSC_0304.JPG" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <!-- text vypsaný uvnitř obrázku-->
              <h3>Školní výlet do Anglie</h3>
              <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- třetí slide-->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/DSC_0558.JPG" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <!--text vypsaný uvnitř obrázku-->
              <h3>Školní výlet do Anglie</h3>
              <p>Londýnské oko/London's Eye</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- navigace slideru-->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    </a>
</section>
```

When I check my site via responsiView, if its responsive, the image itself resizes, but the text inside is still big.

I've tried :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .carousel h3 {
      font-size: 30px;
      }
}
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: You could try [this JQuery plugin](http://fittextjs.com/).  One of my favorites . . .

Comment: wow ! will definitelly try that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe bootstrap already got an idea of what your font-size should be. Since bootstrap uses jQuery/javascript for inline-styling it overrides your media query as it is "closer" to your element and therefore a higher priority.

Either you could right click on the h3 element and select "inspect element" with chrome/firefox to find where the boostrap style is placed (and edit it manually in the .css file), or you could simply add an !important to your style:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .carousel h3 {
      font-size: 30px !important;
      }
}
```

Comment: nice ! this actually is resizing my content, i also got an idea like:
when the site resizes to mobile screen, the text goes off and shows just the button, which user can click and can read the info on another page, is that possible ?

Comment: Yes it is. You could use the same approach, as with the queries, and use visibility:hidden; on the elements you want to hide. A trick is then to create another <div id="button-wrap" style="visibility:hidden"></div> for storing your button which should be visible on smaller screens.

You would then again use your media query to display:visible; on that #button-wrap. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes! definitely, got it working, but now im dealing with button is not resizing :D terrible

Comment: ok!got it guys ! got it working like i wanted ! thanks for the great help and guiding ! :)

Comment: Hehe welcome to the world of resizing :) no worries - glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using JQuery, there is no way to dynamically resize text.  The media query will work, but write it like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   h3.carousel {
      font-size: 30px !important;
      }
}
```